# positioning a div to the right of another div which have dynamic width and prevent it out of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container div and two children divs
one child div will have dynamic content so the width is dynamic
I want the other child div always at the right of the dynamic width div, and this right div will not out of the parent div even if the dynamic content div have many content, which means the right div will stick at the right of the parent div if left div have many content.

Example:

```
+#container-----------------------------+
|+#left---+#right--+                    |
||        |        |                    |
||  Left. | Right. |                    |
||        |        |                    |                                                         
|+--------+--------+                    |
+---------------------------------------+

+#container-----------------------------+
|+#left-----------------------+#right--+|
||                            |        ||
||       too much Left...     | Right. ||
||                            |        ||                                                         
|+----------------------------+--------+|
+---------------------------------------+
```

Can I achieve this just by css?
If not, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You can refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do that. You can use `flex` on the container and give a `flex-basis` property for the children in question so that they won't overflow the container

```css
.container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   display: flex;
}

.left {
   background: red;
   flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.right {
   background: green;
   flex: 1 1 auto;
   min-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  hcbdycu gds7ycgyg cyg sycys vsty7vc7tysv t7cv s7tvc 7ts7c s7tc7vs7t
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by using the `calc` [CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Note that the `300px` in `calc(100% - 300px)` is the "fixed" width of the right div, this guarantees the right div will always stick at the right of the parent div, which in this case the container div.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.left {
  max-width: calc(100% - 300px);
  background: red;
}

.right {
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'>asdf asd asdf asdf asdf ads asddf asfsaf affasfas asfasf</div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```